# mybatis generator can not get database column's comment?

Tags: mybatis-generator

everyone.I try to rewrite the source code of the mybatis generator.but i met a problem that the generator can't get the comment of a database column,and i can't find the problem(i think the source code is right,and don't know what's wrong).here is the source code:

 `ResultSet rs = databaseMetaData.getColumns(localCatalog, localSchema, localTableName, null);
introspectedColumn.setRemarks(rs.getString("REMARKS"));`

introspectedColumn is the generator's class for the database column.
does anybody know about it?Thank you very much!!!